# How can I filter by subdocument field in a mongoose aggregation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to filter the charges of only the specific user for the payment order. Here are my schemas:

```
var PaymentOrderSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  description: {type: String},
  amount: {type: Number},
  charges: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Charge'}],
},

var ChargeSchema = new Schema({
  amount: {type: Number},
  user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  status: {type: String},
  description: {type: String},
  creation_date:{type: Date}
}
```

I am trying to use aggregation, but I'm not able to filter the charges. When I use $ne instead of $eq it does return me the charges, so I know I'm on the right track. Here is my actual code:

```
const paymentOrder = await PaymentOrder.aggregate([
  {$match: {'_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.payment_order_id)}},
  {$project: {
    charges: {$filter: {
      input: '$charges',
      as: 'charge',
      cond: {$eq: ['$$charge.user._id', mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id)]}
    }}
  }}
]);
```

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand it right then, It doesn't work like that you need to either use mongoose's `.populate()` or MongoDB's `$lookup` to first get respective `charges` docs into `charges` array & again populate on `Users` collection to get  users docs & then do a filter on it or get users docs based on condition..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement right, then we can to use $lookup with pipeline

something like this

```
db.paymentOrder.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003") // replace this hard-coded objectId with mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.payment_order_id)
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "charge",
      let: {
        chargeIds: "$charges"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$user",
                "userId1" // replace this with mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id)
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "charges"
    }
  }
])
```

check this [Mongo Plaground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GpVJBx95vl-)

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. This avoided having to have a double reference in each of the schemas!

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation runs on the database server while references are expanded by the driver on the client side, so the value that is actually seen in the pipeline is

```
DBRef("User",ObjectId(...),"DatabaseName")
```

Which can be accessed sort of like an object

```
{"$ref":"User", "$id":ObjectId(...), "$db":"DatabaseName"}
```

But this raises a further problem: field names are not allowed to begin with `$` so this will throw an error:

```
{$eq:["$$charge.user.$id",mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id)]}
```

So you can either skip that step in the aggregation and bring the document back to mongoose to populate, or if matching on the `$id` is all you need, you can use `$objectToArray` to break the DBRef down so you can match:

```
  {$match: {'_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.payment_order_id)}},
  {$unwind: "$charges"},
  {$addFields: {charges:{$objectToArray:"$charges"}}},
  {$match: {charges:{
         $elemMatch:{k:"$id",v:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id}
  }}},
  {$group:{_id:"$_id", charges:{$push:{$arrayToObject("$charges"}}}}}
```

This gives you back the DBRefs that can be expanded by the driver, but this matches against the `_id` of the `charges` document, which is probably not what you want.

However, once you have the `_id` of the charge document, you can use `$lookup` and then filter them, but then we also have to deal with the `user` being a DBref:

```
  {$match: {'_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.payment_order_id)}},
  {$unwind: "$charges"},
  {$addFields: {chargeId:{$filter:{
         input:$objectToArray:"$charges"
         cond:{$eq:["$$this.k","$id"]}
  }}}}, 
  {$lookup:{
       from:"charge",
       localField:"$chargeId.v",
       foreignField:"$_id",
       as: charges
  }},
  {$unwind:"$charges"},
  {$addField:{chargeUser:{$filter:{
        input:{$objectToArray:"$charges.user"},
        cond:{$eq:["$$this.k","$id"]}
  }}}},
  {$match: {"chargeUser.v":mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id)}},  
  {$project:{
        chargeUser:0, 
        chargeId:0
  },
  {$group:{
         _id:"$_id", 
         document:{$first:"$$ROOT"}, 
         charges:{$push:"$charges"}
  }},
  {$addFields:{"document.charges":"$charges"}},
  {$replaceRoot:{newRoot:"$document"}}
```